# About wifi scanning in iOS

Tags: ios, wifi, scanning

I'm wondering if it's possible to scan wifi networking nearby like what WiFi Map did?

And in this application, it can even provide password of the wifi hotspot. Is it legal and what kind of technology is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think this App use IOS technology to scan wifi and offer dynamic password.

In IOS,with public API,you even cannot scan available wifi nearby.

So,I think the Technology of this app is:

1. At first, they offer some public wifi and passowrd.
2. Then user use this app,and they choose to share about connected wifi.So,that the database of this app became bigger and bigger.

Comment: Yes, you're right. After some researches, I found all the wifi infos and passwords are uploaded by users.